# Coffeescript + AngularJS loop to print data to webpage

Tags: html, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm a newbie to this technology and I'm facing a problem I wasn't able to solve yet. I'd like to print some properties of all users in my system. I use `data-ng-repeat` to walk through the users and it works fine for usernames. Nevertheless the other properties keep overwriting each other, so in the end, there are the same data displayed for all users. The back-end function `loadMonthlyStats(mValue.date,user)` works fine and returns data I would await. Problem will be probably on the front end. Any idea how to change the frontend code to avoid this?

Code:

```
<div id="reports" class="panel" data-ng-show="displayReports">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in employees">{{user.getUsername()}}
          <tabset justified="true">
            <tab data-ng-repeat="mValue in monthvalues" data-heading="{{mValue.date | date : 'MMMM yyyy' }}"
                 data-select="loadMonthlyStats(mValue.date,user)">
              <br>
              <!-- next row is being displayed correctly -->
              User: {{user.get('username')}} <br>
              <!-- these rows keeps being overwritten -->
              Worked:{{mValue.monthTime | durationHumanize}} <br>
              Required:{{mValue.targetMonthTime | durationHumanize}} <br>
              {{mValue.completedPercent | number:2}} %
            </tab>
          </tabset>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

durationHumanize filter:

```
angular.module 'myWebApp'
  .filter 'durationHumanize', ->
    (duration) ->
      #duration is in seconds
      mduration = moment.duration(duration, 'seconds')
      hours = Math.floor(mduration.as('hours'))
      minutes = mduration.get('minutes')
      result = ''
      if hours < 10
        result += '0'
      result += hours + 'h '
      if minutes < 10
        result += '0'
      result += minutes + 'm'
      return result
```

Comment: How is monthvalues assigned? Also, what do data-select and data-heading do? I've never seen those before. Are they custom directives?

Comment: monthvalues are assigned in backend function..it simply represents some time period...I think that these directives have something to do with the coffeescript, but I'm not sure - as I said - I'm a total newbie and just would like to make a small adjustment in a code that I inherited from somebody else :-/

Comment: What about durationHumanize? That looks like a custom filter. Can you share the code for that, if you have it?

Comment: It is a custom filter, but the only thing it does is, that it converts time from seconds to "readable" form like hours, minutes and seconds... But I'll post it, just to be sure that the problem is not in this filter...